# html website content not visible on MAC os but working fine on other Operation systems?

Tags: html, css, windows, macos

i have website with html code in simple html tags. but its now showing data when i use chrome and  Firefox MAC, but works fine on windows. i have data in p tag and a tags and more these types of simple tags.

Answer (score 1):

Showing your code would be helpfull. Now I am not even clear what your problem is. It is not working on MAC at all, or just on Safari browser?